# Receiving error message in Python when using if statement(closed)

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

I am not sure why but i am receiving a syntax error in the following code segment:

```
def motor_sat(self, wheel_angular_velocities, limit_value):
     phi1 = wheel_angular_velocities[0]
     phi2 = wheel_angular_velocities[1]
     phi3 = wheel_angular_velocities[2]
    
     if phi1 < -limit_value
      phi1_bar = -limit_value
      elif phi1 <= limit_value and phi1 >= -limit_value
      phi1_bar = phi1
      elif phi1 > limit_value
      phi1_bar = limit_value
```

The error message is:

```
[lab3demo1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[lab3demo1]   File "lab3demo1.py", line 8, in <module>
[lab3demo1]     from myRobot import *
[lab3demo1]   File "/home/user/ele719/controllers/lab3demo1/myRobot.py", line 66
[lab3demo1]     if phi1 < -limit_value
[lab3demo1]                          ^
[lab3demo1] SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You need a colon `:` at the end of the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing colons(`:`) at the end of each if/elif statements, the correct code would be:

```py
def motor_sat(self, wheel_angular_velocities, limit_value):
     phi1 = wheel_angular_velocities[0]
     phi2 = wheel_angular_velocities[1]
     phi3 = wheel_angular_velocities[2]
    
     if phi1 < -limit_value:
         phi1_bar = -limit_value
     elif phi1 <= limit_value and phi1 >= -limit_value:
         phi1_bar = phi1
     elif phi1 > limit_value:
         phi1_bar = limit_value
```